# Fluent Scheduler doesn't run at specific time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, scheduler, fluent

I'm using `Fluent Scheduler` to build a background thread to run at specific time, in my program, it is 4am. Admin can change that time later. Here is my code:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
TaskManager.Initialize(new ParseService(4, 0));
```

**ParseService.cs**

```
public class ParseService : Registry
    {
        public ParseService(int hour, int minute)
        {
            Schedule(ParseHelper.ParseData).ToRunEvery(1).Days().At(hour, minute);
        }
    }
```

I expect it would run at 4am, but when the time hit, nothing happen. I put a break point in the first line of `ParseData` function, it's not hit either. What's wrong with my code? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Is the website not sleeping at that moment? After a while of inactivity it becomes idle.
If so you can start for example a scheduled task to create a webrequest so it wakes up the application.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested solution after initialization for task scheduler

```
while (!JobManager.RunningSchedules.Any())
{
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

it should make the scheduler always running!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Schedule(ParseHelper.ParseData).ToRunEvery(0).Days().At(hour, minute);
```

**ToRunEvery(0)** means we need to start now. 
**ToRunEvery(1)** would wait one interval for first execution - in our case 1 week day